# How to avoid exceptions to freeze entire app in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid exceptions to freeze entire Svelte app?

I'm currently using Svelte v3.12.0 and it looks like if there is an uncaught exception, the entire front end app just freeze and it doesn't recover from errors. I do NOT think wrapping every line of code in every component in try...catch... is a good solution for it.

Answer (score 3):

You could add an event listener to [`unhandledrejection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unhandledrejection_event) and [`error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/error_event) in your `onMount` method and then call [`event.preventDefault()` to stop the error event from bubbling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unhandledrejection_event#preventing_default_handling), which "traps" the error instead of allowing it to throw.

In your `App.svelte` (Svelte) or your root `+layout.svelte` (SvelteKit) you could, for example, handle an unhandled error and show a "toast" notification, show an alert or otherwise handle the error in a more elegant way.

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import { onMount } from 'svelte'
  import { toasts } from '$lib/stores/toasts'

  onMount(() => {
    const report_error = (msg: string = 'unknown error') => {
      toasts.push({
        message: `Unhandled error: ${msg}`,
        type: 'error',
      })
    }

    const handle_rejection = (e: PromiseRejectionEvent) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      report_error(e?.reason)
    }

    const handle_error = (e: ErrorEvent) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      report_error(e?.message)
    }

    window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', handle_rejection)
    window.addEventListener('error', handle_error)

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('unhandledrejection', handle_rejection)
      window.removeEventListener('error', handle_error)
    }
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a limitation in the current implementation of the reactivity system (using a single scheduler). I've documented this and other shortcomings in: [Svelte RFC 40](https://github.com/sveltejs/rfcs/pull/40)

But there is good news on the horizon as Svelte v5 [signal-based approach to reactivity](https://svelte.dev/blog/runes) doesn't seem to have this limitation.

Answer (score -2):

SvelteKit offers a hook called `handleError`, where you can handle errors both on client and server side.

References:

- [handleError](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#shared-hooks-handleerror) hook documentation.
- [Unexpected Errors](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/errors#unexpected-errors)